# Get input value as html

Tags: jquery, html, input, slider

I've been searching but so far no luck. I´m trying to get the value of a `input type="text"` as a html so i can do this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slider").click(function(){

            var bla = $(".slider").val();
            $("p.hi").html(bla);
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the input is as follows:

```
<input class="slider" data-slider-max="50" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-value="0" type="text"> <p class="holi"> INPUT VALUE GOES HERE</p>
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to exactly? as a html means?

Comment: `i´m trying to get the value of a input type="text" ` do `$('#inputid').val()`

Comment: @Pekka he want to get value as a HTMl

Comment: I think he wants $("p.holi").html()

Comment: @Amy I think input has ni HTML only value.. maybe he didnt express the question correctly

Comment: @Pekka Exactly, Thats what I am trying to say

Comment: In your code you have p tag with class holi, but your using $("p.hi") to get the element. use $("p.holi") instead of  $("p.hi")

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `click` event use `input` or `keypress` event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider").on('input', function() {
    $("p.hi").html(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="slider" data-slider-max="50" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-value="0" type="text">
<p class="hi">INPUT VALUE GOES HERE</p>
```

Comment: how could you say he wants to set value to another `<p>` as a html. His question is not clear.

Comment: @Amy : let's wait for his response

Comment: @Amy please check his html snippet ``<p class="holi"> INPUT VALUE GOES HERE</p>``

Comment: @Jalpesh I couldn't get actually what he wants to get.

Comment: @PranavCBalan He is new on SO he is not going to give response :P

Comment: @Amy i predict that he need exactly done he has problem because in jquery he added class "p.hi" insted of he need to add "p.holi"

Comment: yes, im new on SO, im using these sliders https://strukturedkaos.github.io/kickdrop-drops/drops/sliders/ and i want to be able to show the value of the slider on a <p>. Thanks all for the quick responses

Comment: @Amy please read above comment done by oscar. Now what you say.hahahahah

Comment: @Jalpesh You must be Astrologer ;)